# How can I preserve message history across a split

Tags: apache-camel

It seems like if I print the message history before and after a split, history traced before split is lost after the split. is there any way to preserve the message history

Answer (score 1):

When the exchange is `split()` each sub-exchange is newly created by default.

What you're looking for is sharing the unit of work; for example,

```
.split(body()).shareUnitOfWork()
```

See the section *Sharing Unit of Work* in Camel's [Splitter documentation](https://camel.apache.org/splitter.html).

Comment: Even when I add .shareUnitOfWork() I am missing the Property Exchange.MESSAGE_HISTORY. But I am able to retrieve other properties.

Comment: I did a work around by cloning the Message History to another property label and using Aggregation to union it back to all new Exchanges